# Increment FK column value of all rows SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

as my title says, I want to increment a column value of all rows of a table in SQL.

Suppose I have these data in `tab_a` and the `PK` are: `fk_a` and `fk_b` and `fk_c`:

```
|fk_a|fk_b|fk_c|
|1   |2   |2   |
|1   |2   |3   |
```

If I do the following update statement:

```
update tab_a
set fk_c = fk_c + 1
```

My query will complain saying that data (1,2,3) already exists, but it should not complain because I will update every row, hence the row (1,2,3) should become (1,2,4).

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Remove the unique constraint.  Make the change.  Add the constraint back in.

Comment: Please add the data definitions for the table(s) to your question. BTW: maybe you need deferrable constraints. BTW2: it is generally a bad idea to change the value of a Primary key (or unique key / candidate key) Why *is* it unique, anyway?

Comment: Show us the two table definitions.

Comment: And *why* do you name your columns {fk_a, fk_b, fk_c} ? are your children named {dog_1, dog_2, dog_3} ?

Comment: @joop I just gave an example, I never said that my columns are named this...

Comment: @GordonLinoff It worked, thanks, I dropped the index, made the operation, and added the index back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key should be deferrable initially deferred:

```
create table tab_a(
    fk_a int, 
    fk_b int, 
    fk_c int, 
    primary key (fk_a, fk_b, fk_c) deferrable initially deferred
    );

insert into tab_a values 
(1, 2, 3),
(1, 2, 4);

update tab_a
set fk_c = fk_c + 1
returning *;

 fk_a | fk_b | fk_c 
------+------+------
    1 |    2 |    4
    1 |    2 |    5
(2 rows)
```